# PHP is unable to execute sql server stored procedure whereas it successfully running in Microfsoft visual studio

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

When i execute in php this procedure

```
EXEC vehicle_summary_combined_proc @service_id=?,@startDate=?,@endDate=? by following code
            $qry="EXEC vehicle_summary_combined_proc @service_id=?,@startDate=?,@endDate=?";
           // $vehicleSummary[]=select_query($qry);
            $params = array
            (
            array(&$vehid, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
            array(&$assigned_from, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
            array(&$assigned_to, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
            );
            $summary = select_query_proc($qry,$params); 
 function select_query_proc($query,$params)
{
        $dblink=connecttodbmssql();
        $options = array("Scrollable"=>"buffered");

        $qry=sqlsrv_query($dblink,$query,$params,$options);// or die( $query . " ". mysql_error());
        //print_r($qry);
        if( $qry === false ) 
        {
          return [];
           //die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
         }

        $num=sqlsrv_num_rows($qry);
         //print_r($num);
        $num_field=sqlsrv_num_fields($qry);
        //print_r($num_field);
        $metaData =sqlsrv_field_metadata($qry);
        //print_r($metaData);
        $count=count($metaData);
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
        $fname[]=$metaData[$i]["Name"];

        }
        //print_r($fname);
        for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
        $result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry);
        //print_r($result);
        foreach($fname as $key => $value ) {
          //print_r($result[$value]);
            $arr[$i][$value]=$result[$value];
            }
        }
        //print_r($arr);
        return $arr;

       // Close the connection.
      sqlsrv_close($dblink);

}
```

This gave me following errors and it runs successfully in visual studio

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'i2'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'i2'.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'tel_odometer'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'tel_odometer'.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'time1'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'time1'.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'lat1'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'lat1'.
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'long1'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'long1'.
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'time2'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'time2'.
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'gps_speed'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'gps_speed'.
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'address1'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'address1'.
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'time1'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'time1'.
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'i2'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'i2'.
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'gps_speed'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'gps_speed'.
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'i2'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'i2'.
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'gps_speed'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'gps_speed'.
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'tel_temperature'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'tel_temperature'.
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42S22
            [SQLSTATE] => 42S22
            [1] => 207
            [code] => 207
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'tel_temp2'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'tel_temp2'.
        )

)
```

**My procedure code is :-**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[vehicle_summary_combined_proc]
@service_id nvarchar(20),@startDate nvarchar(100),@endDate nvarchar(100)
as 
begin
--SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
--BEGIN TRAN

set nocount on
declare @tbl_tel varchar(20)
declare @offset integer
declare @tname varchar(20)

set @tname='tbl_temp_report'
--set @tbl_tel='tbl_telemetry_mar20'
--set @tname='temp_report_' +(left(DATENAME(MONTH,@endDate),3))
set @tbl_tel='tbl_telemetry_apr20'+(left(DATENAME(month,@endDate),3))+(right(DATENAME(year,@endDate),2))
set @offset=(select tz.utc_offset from tbl_users u inner join tbl_timezone tz 
on u.timezone_id=tz.id inner join tbl_services s
on s.sys_user_id=u.id where s.id=@service_id) 

set @startDate=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,@offset,convert(datetime,@startDate))),121)
set @endDate=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,@offset,convert(datetime,@endDate))),121)

create table #temp( 
startdate date null,
[sys_service_id] int null,
start_location varchar(max) null,
end_location varchar(max) null,
[total_idle_time] nvarchar(100) null,
[total_running_time] nvarchar(100) null,
[total_halt_time] nvarchar(100) null,
[total_distance] nvarchar(100) null,
[max_idle] nvarchar(100) null,
[idle_latitude] float null,
[idle_longitude] float null,
[idle_address] varchar(max) null,
[idle_start_time] datetime null,
[idle_end_time] datetime null,
[max_halt] nvarchar(100) null,
[halt_latitude] float null,
[halt_longitude] float null,
[halt_address] varchar(max) null,
[halt_start_time] datetime null,
[halt_end_time] datetime null,
[avg_speed] float null,
[max_speed] float null,
start_lat float null,
start_long float null,
end_lat float null,
end_long  float null,
[avg_temp] float null,
[min_temp] float null,
[max_temp] float null,
[avg_temp2] float null ,
[min_temp2] float null,
[max_temp2] float null,
[status] varchar(10))
truncate table #temp;


if convert(date,@startDate)=convert(date,GETDATE())
begin

set @startDate=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,-@offset,@startDate)),121)
set @endDate=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,-@offset,@endDate)),121)

insert into #temp
exec daily_console_report_latest @service_id,@startDate,@endDate

end

else
begin

declare @enddate1 varchar(max);
declare @startdate1 varchar(max);

if convert(date,@startDate)=convert(date,@endDate)
begin

set @endDate1=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,-@offset,@endDate)),121)

end
else
begin
set @endDate1=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,-@offset,convert(varchar(max),(convert(date,@startDate)))+' 23:59:00')),121)
end
set @startDate=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,-@offset,@startDate)),121)

--print @startDate +' ' +@endDate1

begin try
insert into #temp
exec daily_console_report_monthly @service_id,@startDate,@endDate1
end try
begin catch
end catch

update #temp set startdate=CONVERT(date,@endDate1) where startdate is null
set @startDate=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,@offset,@startDate)),121)
declare @diff int;
set @diff = DATEDIFF(day,@startDate,@endDate) -1 ;

--print @diff

while(@diff >0) 
begin

insert into #temp
select top 1 startdate, sys_service_id,start_address,end_address,total_idle_time,total_running_time,total_halt_time,
total_distance,max_idle,idle_latitude,idle_longitude,idle_address,idle_start_time,idle_end_time,max_halt,halt_latitude,
halt_longitude,halt_address,halt_start_time,halt_end_time,avg_speed,max_speed,null as start_lat,null as start_long,
null as end_lat,null as end_long,avg_temp,min_temp,max_temp,avg_temp2,min_temp2,max_temp2,
status from tbl_vehicle_summary where sys_service_id=@service_id and startdate=convert(date,DATEADD(DAY,@diff,@startDate))
set @diff = @diff -1;
end

set @startdate1=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,-@offset,convert(varchar(max),(convert(date,@endDate)))+' 00:00:00')),121)

if convert(date,@endDate)>=convert(date,GETDATE())


begin

set @endDate=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,-@offset,convert(datetime,@endDate))),121)

insert into #temp
exec daily_console_report_latest @service_id,@startdate1,@endDate 
end

else
begin
set @endDate=convert(varchar(max),(DATEADD(minute,-@offset,convert(datetime,@endDate))),121)

if @endDate1 <> @endDate
begin
--print 'hi'
insert into #temp
exec daily_console_report_monthly @service_id,@startDate1,@endDate
end
update #temp set startdate=CONVERT(date,@endDate) where startdate is null
end
end 


declare @total_idle int,@total_running int,@total_halt int,@total_distance float,@max_idle varchar(max),
@max_halt varchar(max),@avg_Speed float,@max_speed float;

set @total_idle = (select sum(dbo.to_minutes(total_idle_time)) from #temp where total_idle_time is not null);
set @total_running = (select sum(dbo.to_minutes(total_running_time)) from #temp where total_running_time is not null);
set @total_halt = (select sum(dbo.to_minutes(total_halt_time)) from #temp where total_halt_time is not null);
set @total_distance = (select sum(convert(float,total_distance)) from #temp where total_distance is not null);
set @max_idle = (select max(dbo.to_minutes(max_idle)) from #temp where max_idle is not null);
set @max_halt = (select max(dbo.to_minutes(max_halt)) from #temp where max_halt is not null);
set @avg_Speed = (select AVG(avg_speed) from #temp where avg_speed is not null);
set @max_speed = (select max(max_speed) from #temp);

if @total_distance = 0
begin
set @max_speed = 0
end


insert into #temp values(null,
@service_id,null,null,
dbo.to_hour(@total_idle),
dbo.to_hour(@total_running),
dbo.to_hour(@total_halt),
convert(varchar(max),@total_distance),
dbo.to_hour(@max_idle),
(select top 1 idle_latitude from #temp where max_idle=dbo.to_hour(@max_idle)),
(select top 1 idle_longitude from #temp where max_idle=dbo.to_hour(@max_idle)),
(select top 1 idle_address  from #temp where max_idle=dbo.to_hour(@max_idle)),
(select top 1 idle_start_time  from #temp where max_idle=dbo.to_hour(@max_idle)),
(select top 1 idle_end_time  from #temp where max_idle=dbo.to_hour(@max_idle)),
dbo.to_hour(@max_halt),
(select top 1 halt_latitude from #temp where max_halt=dbo.to_hour(@max_halt)),
(select top 1 halt_longitude from #temp where max_halt=dbo.to_hour(@max_halt)),
(select top 1 halt_address from #temp where max_halt=dbo.to_hour(@max_halt)),
(select top 1 halt_start_time from #temp where max_halt=dbo.to_hour(@max_halt)),
(select top 1 halt_end_time  from #temp where max_halt=dbo.to_hour(@max_halt)),
@avg_Speed,@max_speed,(select top 1 start_lat  from #temp),
(select top 1 start_long  from #temp),
(select top 1 end_lat  from #temp),
(select top 1 end_long  from #temp),
null,null,null,null,null,null,null)

select * from #temp order by startdate
--COMMIT TRANSACTION 
end
```

**Above is my stored procedure code it runs on visual studio successfully dont know why this problem occured while i hit from PHP sqlsrv functions please help me out from this problem i have been debug the procedure multiple times but could not traced single error why it is stuck in executing same procedure by php

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: (1) your PHP is connecting to a different server or different database with its own stored procedure named `vehicle_summary_combined_proc`, or (2) your PHP is executing a stored procedure named `vehicle_summary_combined_proc` but in a different schema (i.e.: not the `dbo` schema).

Comment: Are you using same user to connect to sql server from both PHP and Visual Studio?

Comment: The error message you pasted does not seem to be related to columns in your stored procedure. Are you sure it is the correct error message you pasted?

Comment: What is the expected output?